# Unable to bind model to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

This is a logging project, the Title provides the name of the item and the message logs each stage. Therefore, there are many Messages for each Title.

For the purpose of asking a question, I am simplifying my objects.

My Log class has 2 properties.

```
List<LogDetails>
string Title
```

And my LogDetails class has 1 property:

```
string Message
```

I am not able to bind the Message to my XAML. The Title binds as desired.

My xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="BackUps.Logging.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myData="clr-namespace:BackUps.Logging"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:Log}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding LogDetailsList}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:LogDetails}">
              <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
  </Grid>
```

and my code behind

```
  public MainWindow(List<Log> logs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = logs;
    }
```

My result is (where you can see the missing entries):

[image]

This is the Auto's window, which shows the object I'm trying to bind.

[image]

What have I missed or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, and fixed it by (completely) changing the xaml to the form:

```
<Grid>
  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:Log}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding LogDetailsList}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myData:LogDetails}>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
  </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, sadly the same error continues. I am updating my question to show the class properties and details as this may help.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but might help debugging, what happens when you use `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />` for the inner datatemplate?

Comment: Paul, if I change it from <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" /> to <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /> then it displays the Type on screen. So, I can only assume it's the property name "Message" is disliked for some reason?

Comment: Yes! The full name of the type: BackUps.Logging.LogDetails

Comment: Is `Message` implemented as a public property?

Comment: Ahhh, no, it was a field. Just 'updated' to use properties, and all binding works as desired. Thank you. Beers on me for this, thank you for sticking with me and getting this solved.